# File upload extension validation issue

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am working in a project Laravel 5.4. When I upload a file(doc,docx,pdf) it uploaded successfully. But If I implement validation in controller like

```
public function save_attachment(Request $request){

   $this->validate(request(), [
        'user_name'        => 'required',
        'attachment'       => 'required|mimes:pdf,doc,docx',
    ]); 
 .....  }
```

it redirect to the input form with `The attachment must be a file of type: pdf, doc, docx.`

I tried with doc and pdf file it returns same.  Where is my problem thank you.

Comment: Can you show your controller code where You use validator.

Comment: You should refer this link - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-mimes

Comment: Can you show your form view in the above code example.

Comment: where do you get `request()`? Have you tried with `$this->validate($request, [` ?